# Processing large excel data in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to read & process excel file data in nodejs. The file may contain thousands of rows. What I want to do is **process this data in chunks of say 500 rows**. Once 500 rows are processed,**response should be sent to client** like 500 rows processed, 1000 rows processed, and so on while the server continues to process remaining data until it is completed. I am not sure how this can be done in node.js. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming when you say excel, you mean csv file. For this big file, streaming is the best way. There is a package called [etl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/etl) which does that job for you. something like this

```
fs.createReadStream('scores.csv')
  // parse the csv file
  .pipe(etl.csv())
  // map `date` into a javascript date and set unique _id
  .pipe(etl.map(d => {
    d._id = d.person_id;
    d.date = new Date(d.date);
    return d;
  }))
  // collect 1000 records at a time for bulk-insert
  .pipe(etl.collect(1000))  
  // upsert records to elastic with max 10 concurrent server requests
  .pipe(etl.elastic.index(esClient,'scores','records',{concurrency:10}))
  // Switch from stream to promise chain and report done or error
  .promise()
  .then( () => console.log('done'), e => console.log('error',e));
```

The example above reads the csv, collect records and pushes to elasticsearh. You can get an idea from this.